# Find document in mongodb based on value found in array

Tags: mongodb

In my mongodb collection I have a structure:

```
A: {var1 : atr1, var2 : atr2, var3 : {key1 :[1], key2 : [2,4,6]}}
B: {var1 : atr1, var2 : atr2, var3 : {key1 :[2,3], key2 : [4]}}
C: {var1 : atr1, var2 : atr2, var3 : {key1 :[3], key2 : [4,5,6]}}
```

My goal is to get A, B or C out based on whats in the key, but regardless if its in key1 or key2, or even key99 if it would go that far.

I tried to use

```
{'var3' : {$elemMatch : {object}}},

{'var3' : {$elemMatch : {$elemMatch : {object}}}}.
```

in combination with `$all`, `$in`, `$eq`, but when running that query I will get.

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
```

Is there a way in mongodb to say in check every array in var3 and give back the documents in which a 2 is found?

In the above said structure it would be A and B.

Comment: @srinivasy sorry for the late response, the issue is fixed with your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on objects in either mongoDB or most programming languages is mostly thru `.` notation. So if you wanted to check 2 exists as value in a key of `var3` object then you need to specify `'var3.SpecifickeyNo' : {$in :[2]}`, but since you need to check against all keys directly on `var3` without specifying key num, then please try this :

```
db.YourCollectionName.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { "mergeAsArray": { $objectToArray: "$var3" } } },
    {
        $addFields:
        {
            mergeAsArray:
            {
                $reduce: {
                    input: '$mergeAsArray.v',
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        } // values of all keys in var3 object are merged into a field mergeAsArray
    }, { $match: { 'mergeAsArray': { $in: [2] } } }, { $project: { mergeAsArray: 0 } }])
```

**Ref :** [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#examples) , [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) , [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html)

**Collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfd095e3cd30d038bb4f875"),
    "var1" : "atr1",
    "var2" : "atr2",
    "var3" : {
        "key1" : [ 
            1.0
        ],
        "key2" : [ 
            2.0, 
            4.0, 
            6.0
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfd095e3cd30d038bb4f876"),
    "var1" : "atr1",
    "var2" : "atr2",
    "var3" : {
        "key1" : [ 
            2.0, 
            3.0
        ],
        "key2" : [ 
            4.0
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfd095e3cd30d038bb4f877"),
    "var1" : "atr1",
    "var2" : "atr2",
    "var3" : {
        "key1" : [ 
            3.0
        ],
        "key2" : [ 
            4.0, 
            5.0, 
            6.0
        ]
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfd095e3cd30d038bb4f875"),
    "var1" : "atr1",
    "var2" : "atr2",
    "var3" : {
        "key1" : [ 
            1.0
        ],
        "key2" : [ 
            2.0, 
            4.0, 
            6.0
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfd095e3cd30d038bb4f876"),
    "var1" : "atr1",
    "var2" : "atr2",
    "var3" : {
        "key1" : [ 
            2.0, 
            3.0
        ],
        "key2" : [ 
            4.0
        ]
    }
}
```

From the above input value `2` is matched against `var3.key2` in first document & `var3.key1` in second document.

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure what you want to do with your field var3 what is the nature of A,B and C. 
But if you want to go throught and array list you could use an `$unwind`

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").aggregate([
        {
            $project : {
                "keyN": "var3", 
            }
        },
        { $unwind : "$keyN"},
        {
            $project : {
                "varName": {$elemMatch : {key : "$keyN"}}, 
            }
        },
        ])
```